# Do I need to be influential with my human teammate to win Tourism Victory?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I'm playing a game with a friend where I'm doing my best to stack tourism. I've noticed that I'm still "exotic" to him and he has a TON of culture. I also cannot generate many tourism bonuses for him because "open borders" does not exist.

Do I have to become influential with my human ally (teammate) to win a culture/tourism victory? (more tourism than his total culture)

I cannot find the information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I have no idea. But after firing up a test game with me and an AI in a team (with 4 other AI players) the evidence *seems* to indicate you do need to influence your teammate.

First, the victory screen shows my teammate as one of the 'targets' in the cultural victory progress:
[image]

Second, the culture overview screen for victory indicates I'm influential with **0 of 5** other civilisations, implying I need to influence my teammate as there's only 4 other players.
[image]

I'm not claiming this is a definitive answer, but until we've some strong evidence (someone winning or not when all players except their teammate are influenced) this is probably the best we've got.

Comment: U are correct it requires influential in all players teammates or not. Typically if one teammate was going culture the other teammate would not

Comment: @Paralytic Doesn't this seem broken though? I mean you can't get open borders bonus from your teammate. My teammate wasn't going for culture, he was going diplomacy but he had more culture than me for  a long time from city-state gifts. He still produces a lot! With a computer civ, i could kill a rival who had a bunch of culture, or do open borders at least. I think there is even some other bonuses that I may not get. Anyway, it doesn't matter too much because diplomatic victory is so easy he'll win long before I do, but I did want to know

Comment: Anyway, I'm marking this as the answer unless someone clearly refutes it. If my friend wins diplo victory we may reload and avoid diplomatic victory and see about the tourism victory just to make sure

Comment: Nah I've won a cultural victory before the modern era

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to become influential with your human ally. With that influence you will be able to boost tourism between the two of you.